# Could we add a comment option and/or flagging for "help and improvement"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The 'Help and Improvement' queue encourages to edit posts (as skipping it the only other option).

I'm often met with questions that should have been flagged or commented on in Triage to encourage the author to edit the question themselves as only that may be an option to make the question comprehensable.

Could we add an **encouragement comment** option for the author, like

> Please read about how to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

As well as the 'Unsalvageble' button from Triage to let 'Help and Improvement' catch anything that should be flagged but didn't get flagged? (Probably because of unexperienced users reviewing on Triage, which is generally a good thing)

I'm using 'discussion' since I guess there will be one.

Comment: Maybe I'm cynical, but I think this type of "encouragement" for the author should come from having their question closed.

Comment: @CodyGray That's where the flagging option comes into play. I tend to review this on a case-by-case basis; some questions need closing, others just a little extra and might be (kind of) answerable even when not exactly good, such that closing would be overkill and actually discouragement.

Comment: Seems like you may have a misunderstanding of what closing a question means. It is done to give the OP an opportunity to improve their question, such as detailed in [ask]. Indeed, the close message indicates what needs to be improved (more or less). Additionally, users should have already read [ask], so prompting them again seems like it won't be encouraging at all...

Comment: Actually, I have positive experience using comments rather that close votes. However, in the description of the review queue, commenting is also encouraged if only the author may edit the question to salvage it.